# VBO must be bound after VAO

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, vao

Code:

```
void render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLfloat vertices[6][4] = {
        { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
        { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
        { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },

        { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
        { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
        { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }
    };

    glUseProgram(shadptr->progGraphics);
    glBindVertexArray(vao_g);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_g);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6 * 4, vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    glUseProgram(shadptr->progText);
    glBindVertexArray(vao_t);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_t);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6 * 4, vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(winptr->window);
}

void set_buffers()
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao_g);
    glBindVertexArray(vao_g);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo_g);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_g);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), nullptr);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao_t);
    glBindVertexArray(vao_t);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo_t);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_t);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), nullptr);
}
```

I have a problem. I don't know why I have to bind vbo after binding vao in render function. When I don't bind vbo, in RenderDoc I have an error "glDrawArrays has generated an error (GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY)" and in mesh output, in VS input I see wrong values or --- value.

Comment: *"I don't know why I have to bind vbo after binding vao in render function"* - Because you try to create and initialize the buffer object 's data store by [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) and for this the buffer has to be bound. Move this code to `set_buffers` and it will be sufficient to bind the vertex array object.

Comment: @Rabbid76 This should probably posted as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know why I have to bind vbo after binding vao in render function"

Because you try to create and initialize the buffer object 's data store by [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) and for this the buffer has to be bound.

I recommend to move the code, which creates and initializes the buffer to `set_buffers`. Then it will be sufficient to bind the vertex array object only, in the function `render`:

```
void render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(shadptr->progGraphics);
    glBindVertexArray(vao_g);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    glUseProgram(shadptr->progText);
    glBindVertexArray(vao_t);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(winptr->window);
}
```

```
void set_buffers()
{
    ....

    GLfloat vertices[6][4] = {
        { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
        { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
        { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },

        { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
        { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
        { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }
    };

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_g);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6 * 4, vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_t);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6 * 4, vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

---

I recommend to use [`glBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml), to change the content of a buffer. This will update the buffer, but doesn't creates and initializes a completely new data store and thus would be much more efficient.